# What 50’s movie has aliens doing open-heart surgery in a cave, and Richard Conte on a beach?

Tags: story-identification

I found Gwendolyn Greer’s [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66214/51379) about ‘Pandora’s box’ on Google because I also wanted the name of the film which has the scene she describes, i.e. ‘Kiss Me Deadly’.

There is a similar sci-fi film which I saw circa 1959, in a cinema when I could only get admission to see a ‘U’ film, for an unaccompanied child, but it should have had an adult rating.

The first scene I remember is a man standing in his wet suit in a small boat at
sea, when a radioactive cloud rolls over him, and the wet suit collapses as if empty.

Next I’m convinced I saw Richard Conte standing on a beach, staring with great trepidation at a partly-opened, snuff-box-like object, which is hissing at him,
reminiscent of ‘Kiss Me Deadly’.

Lastly there is a group of bug-eyed aliens in a cave. They have an unconscious man
on the operating table in front of them, and his heart is sat on the outside of his chest, beating away.

I’ve looked at a list of Richard Conte’s films on Wikipedia, and at lists of sci-fi/horror & noir films of the late fifties and early sixties but I can’t find the name of this film.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The “bug-eyed” aliens doing heart surgery reminds me a bit of *Killers from Space* (1954). I’m not sure that the rest matches, though. Is there any possibility that you might have seen a series of commercials, a double feature, or perhaps be combining two films?

Comment: In fact, I just watched the relevant scene from *Killers from Space*, and it is a perfect match. You could perhaps be recalling more than one film.

Comment: Given that it’s very likely that you are combining two films, perhaps you could see if the [*Killers from Space* scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JuPEHWG97H8) is the one you remember. If it is (thus confirming that you are recalling multiple films here), you could edit to make that the question, and ask the other part or parts separately.

Comment: Thanks Adamant,
I've had a look at 'killers from
outer space', starring Peter Graves, and I agree
that the scene of alien
surgery in a cave is a good
match. 1954.
However, l believe that this
scene was copied in the 
later film circa 1959 in which
Richard Conte had a part.
All the scenes l mentioned
were in the same film.
Geoff.

Comment: I’ve been looking around Richard Conte’s filmography, and I haven’t found any likely suspects yet. But I’ll keep looking.

Comment: Could there have been some sort of anthology or something?

Comment: Thanks Adamant,
This film may have been an update of the 1954 version.
Richard C may have been
staring at a communicator
receiving instructions from
the aliens.
 Just guesswork sadly.      The wetsuit scene was very
 well done, startling in fact, 
but I've never seen
it since, whereas I've seen 
'kiss me deadly' on TV
 repeated several times,
 along with the fifties ' The
fly', and 'The lncredible
Shrinking Man' etc.
My local paper for the time,
the 'Kentish Mercury' may
be archived at the British
Library but l need some
advice from them how to
access the material.
Geoff.

Answer (score 5):

### [*Killers from Space* (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047149/)

[image]

The final scene mentioned is a **perfect** match for one found in *Killers from Space*.

Here are the aliens, with very protruding eyes (probably in reality ping-pong balls taped over the actors’ real eyes):

[image]

Here’s the unconscious man with his heart beating outside his chest:

[image]

The aliens are indeed performing surgery on him in a cave, by waving strange instruments:

[image]

---

This matches so well that is almost certainly the scene described in the question. However, while it *has* been featured in various films, as indicated in this list of [connections](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047149/movieconnections), none are around 1959. In addition, a look at Richard Conte’s [filmography](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0002017/) does not seem to reveal any movies from around 1959 that could plausibly have these scenes.